# How to produce a XHR log silently with Chrome

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, logging, xmlhttprequest, trace

I would like to spot a "random" bug on a site. In order to do that I would like to have all the XHR requests saved in a log file, which is a very easy thing. The problem is that I'm not the user, so I have to set up someone else's machine to do that.

The problem is that the user doesn't know how to use the "developer tools" so I would like to have a tools that keep trace of everything without bothering the user. Bear in mind that this bug can occur once in a day and during this time the user can close the browser and re-open it. Do you have any suggestion?   thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way would be to make the logs from within the site that you're trying to observe.
If you don't have access to it, another solution might be to find/develop a browser extension that logs any xhr to a local file.